# Why will my javascript no run from php?

Tags: javascript, php, echo, alert

I am making a basic login web application and I am using the echo function in php to run some javascript to alert the user they got their username/password incorrect, for ease of doing something instead of just going to the main index.php file with no text in the form box's. For some reason my alert doesn't come up but I get redirected to my index.php. I don't know why this is happening?

/ / / This is the code that only half of it is running / / /

```
echo 
    '<script type="text/javascript">'
    ,'alert("a");'
    ,'</script>'
;
header("Location: /");
```

?>

Can someone please tell me if I have any syntax errors or any errors at all?

Thank you in advance -mjacob652

---

index.php's body

```
<div id="header">
<h1> Welcome to S.O.G <br/> Specials Operations Gaming </h1>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<h2> Please Log In </h2>
<form id="form" action="/Account/php/login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"/> <br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> <br/>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

---

login.php just has the sql stuff and the echo and header

Comment: if you change location, browser will redirect before script will be executed.

Comment: Your header will not work after this echo statement. What are you trying to do?  Javascript and php are two different languages, so php has nothing todo with your javascript, which is by the way a valid statement for alert.

Comment: @MuhammedM. header will work if output_buffering is on, which is by default http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633002/why-i-dont-get-headers-already-sent-error

Comment: @MuhammedM. I'm trying to alert the logging in user that his username or password is incorrect

Comment: No you are echoing some javascript to the current page, and then redirecting to a completly different page. Major waste of time

Comment: @jcubic How might I go about alerting the user his credentials are incorrect and go back to the index.php file

Comment: @RiggsFolly same question for you

Comment: Do you have a `login.php` and an `index.php` or is this all happening in one script?

Comment: why r u using `header("Location: /");` if you want to use `alert()`

Comment: a index.php with the form and when you submit the form it calls the login.php

Comment: Show us more of your actual code, then we can make sensible suggestions rather than guesses

Comment: @jcubic outbut buferring is not on by default in PHP. What he is trying to accomplish, doesnt have to do with ob_, he shouldnt turn it on just to do this echo statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple and quick workaround:

```
echo 
    '<script type="text/javascript">'
    ,'alert("a"); window.location.href = "/";'
    ,'</script>';
```

In this way user will be redirect right after `alert` dialog popup will be closed.

Comment: Thank you so much after further review i noticed it was a totally different problem makeing nothing appear, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> Why will my javascript no run from php?

Imagine that your are in a php script that will redirect to itself everytime it loads.

Chrome will give you

> redirected you too many times. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

while in Mozilla

> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.

> Can someone please tell me if I have any syntax errors or any errors
>   at all?

Of Course you dont have any syntax error, it just the redirection is infinite in your current code.

Comment: No it only redirects to the login.php when you submit the form

Comment: @mjacob652 when your form is submitted to and it goes to your login.php and had alert then after that alert, php will execute `header("Location: /");`  redirecting to login.php itself. that would become infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Every thing in php Code will run first because we request to server so server will translate server code first so it will can result back. but server will translate echo and then meet header so it will redirect without echo anything